# How to add javascript to a joomla 1.5 article using TinyMCE editor?

Tags: javascript, joomla, tinymce

I'm having trouble trying to get JavaScript to show up on a Joomla! article using the TinyMCE editor. I've set all the settings I should based on Google searches and it's still not showing. The JavaScript code is commented out as shown in screenshots below.

[image: Click here to view TinyMCE settings]

[image: Click here to view Chrome Developer Tool Screenshot]

Any help is greatly appreciated. TQ!

Answer (score 1):

Though many WYSIWYG editors claim `<script>` support, I would suggest using the "None" editor when adding the JavaScript code to your posts. I use [Switch Editor](http://anything-digital.com/community-products/editor-switcher-the-convenient-and-free-editor-selector.html) to quickly change editors. After installing and activating the package:

1. Switch to "None" editor
2. Open the article
3. Add the embed code
4. Save the article
5. Switch back to your favorite WYSIWYG editor to edit other articles

This will give you the least problems. Unfortunately, the package is only available for Joomla! 2.5+. However, there is an alternative here:
http://www.joomler.net/download/81-joomla15-plugin/959-editor-switcher-for-joomla15-released.html

---

On a side note, you should upgrade your site away from Joomla! 1.5 ASAP!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! I've installed Switch Editor as suggested and created a new article. However, the javascripts are still commented out. This is my url http://dignityforchildren.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=147

Comment: Did you select the "None" editor first, before editing the article? If you did, you would only see a box with code, no WYSIWYG toolbar. Also, try pasting your entire article contents here and share the link: https://jsfiddle.net/ That way we can compare the article contents to the web contents to see the difference.

Comment: Under global configuration, i selected "Editor-Switcher" for default WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: Then under editor-switcher plugin, i enabled it and selected "Editor - No editor" for default editor. I saved it. Next, i create a new article and i keep on seeing the WYSIWYG editor. Same goes if i just set "Editor - No editor" under global configuration.

Comment: my website: http://dignityforchildren.org/ndex.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=152   The JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zmwsqtym/